# Different table sizes after duplicate tables?

Tags: postgresql

I duplicated my table with:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1;
```

I'm checking the sizes of thee 2 tables:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('table1'));

SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('table2'));
```

But I'm getting different sizes (`size(table1) > size(table2)`).

```
size table1 = 2064MB

size table2 = 821MB
```

How can it be ? Can I be sure that all the data from `table1` was duplicated into `table2` ?

Comment: Try `vacuum full table1`